# How to embed `.ui` file on a binary gtk application?

Tags: c, gtk, binaryfiles

I'm working on a GTK application that loads a `.ui` file from a relative path but the compiled binary file is not able to find the interface file later.

What's the common way of dealing with `.ui` files? Is there a way to "embed" the `.ui` file within the binary distribution?

Comment: Some comments about it from GTK+ documentation:  https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html

Comment: That doesn't really talk about the distribution of said `.ui` files, which is what the person is asking about. Unfortunately, that tutorial doesn't really talk about distribution methods other than shoving your `.ui` files in `/usr/share`...

Comment: @andlabs exactly, I need a self contained distribution, don't want to make a package.

Comment: That link shows how to recode to include the ".ui" file in the program, and why it may not be a good idea, as well as where the ".ui" is usually stored on a system.  HOWEVER, if your question is how to change the executable (i.e. the binary) to embed the ".ui", or change the ".ui's"  location... then you are right, that link doesn't tell you how to do that.  And I'm not sure you can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is up to you, but I can name two "standard" ways of doing so:

The first is to require your `.ui` files to be externally installed in something like `/usr/share/[your program name here]/` or similar. This is probably not what you want to do (and I would personally not recommend this, but that's just my opinion...).

The other way is to use a [GResource](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html) file. GResource is part of GLib, which GTK+ is built on top of. Everything you need to know is listed on that page, under "Description". (This is the method I would prefer using, at least for C and Vala projects; the latter especially as the `GtkTemplate` attribute can invoke GtkBuilder transparently.)